# Preview result of update operation

Tags: meteor, minimongo

Is it possible to apply a modifier to a document and see the result before doing the actual update query?

Something like a virtual/simulated update.

My purpose is to validate any possible update inside a `before` hook through an external service that only accepts some final, post-operation document and then possibly abort the operation.

Comment: did you mean some thing like commit rollback in mysql?

Comment: I'm thinking something like transforming a document object in accordance with the contents of a modifier object too see that the new document looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimongo has a function that can be used: `LocalCollection._modify(doc, modifier)`. In order to load `LocalCollection` on the server, add `minimongo` to `local/packages`

Answer (score 0):

write your logic for logic inside a [allow,deny function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow)

> update(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier)
>
> fieldNames is an array of the (top-level) fields in doc that the
>   client wants to modify, for example ['name', 'score'].
>
> modifier is the raw Mongo modifier that the client wants to execute;
>   for example, {$set: {'name.first': "Alice"}, $inc: {score: 1}}.

```
Posts.allow({
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    //you can return false here, if you dont want to update db
  },
});
```

Comment: I don't think I will be able to see the transformed document here, either. `doc` is the current version, not the modified version.

Comment: yes. but you can check for fieldNames that are going to change. and decide to update or not.

Comment: Thank, but this is not what I'm asking.